# django model from as radio select

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple model form:

```
 class ProductSelectionForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Product
```

and the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=155)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

But if I render the form using the  `{{ form.as_p }}` tag it just renders the form as a single text input. How can I get the form to render as radio select options, with the `name` as the option label and the `pk` as the value? I have tried using `widget` but no joy.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want a modelform for that. They're for creating and editing model instances. Instead, what you seem to want is a form to choose existing instances: for that, use a normal form with a ModelChoiceField:

```
class ProductSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Comment: Ahh quite right! One extra question - how do I eliminate the empty choice which appears when the form is rendered?

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) - set `empty_label=None`.